# tell yum to ignore a single dependency

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I'm trying to install `winswitch` on CentOs 6. It requires `nxagent`. But in centos, the package name is `nx`. Is there a way to tell yum to skip checking the `nxagent` dependency (I installed `nx` already)? Specifying `--skip-broken` skips the whole thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally `yum` doesn't have options to ignore a single package from the dependencies.  Option `--skip-broken` ignores all unresolved dependences.

You can try `yum --exclude=packagename` but it excludes a specific package by name or glob from updates on all repositories, not from dependencies.

Comment: `yum --exclude` doesn't work on dependencies

Comment: @DrStrangepork yes I know I wrote that in my answer

Comment: Neither `--exclude` nor `--skip-broken` helps bypass one or more dependencies in the way that `rpm --nodeps` does.

Comment: Go to the second answer.

Answer (score 73):

The `rpm` command has the `--nodeps` option that you can use. A challenge is that `rpm` by itself is not aware of yum repositories. The following command will install or update the package, ignoring dependencies, but automatically looking up the download URL from your repositories with `repoquery` which is in package `yum-utils`.

```
rpm -Uvh --nodeps $(repoquery --location winswitch)
```

After that, a regular `yum update` will likely succeed without dependency errors.

Comment: $(repoquery --location winswitch) did not work for me. However, one can download .rpm package via "yumdownloader --destdir=. package-name" . "rpm -U" means upgrade. If the package was not installed, one can use "rpm -i" for that. yumdownloader is from yum-utils (dnf-utils in my case).

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to install package that has not been designed for the OS, i.e. if it was designed for CentOS it would require `nx` correctly.

Another workaround for the problem is to create and install a small shim RPM package that contains no files, but in the spec file contains the following lines (amongst others):

```
requires: nx
provides: nxagent
```

That way the dependency should be satisfied however it may be expecting files to be in a location that differs between the `nxagent` package it expects to have installed and the `nx` package that CentOS provides.

Comment: Would like to see a more complete solution here. How do you create and install a small shim RPM package?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use rpmrebuild to change the rpm metadata to point at the new package name. this will then be "your" package, but is cleaner as far as the rpm dependencies go.
There's no disadvantage over using --nodeps I think.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner example does it ( tigervnc-server is the package being installed )

```
rpm -ivh --nodeps ` yumdownloader tigervnc-server | perl -ne 'print $2 if(/^(\[.+\]\s*|)(.*?\.rpm)[\s:]/)'`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use yumdownloader to automatically download the package for you, then use rpm -i and --nodeps to install the package without dependency checks.