# Installed software from source, how to say yum not to install it from package?

Tags: centos, yum, package-management

On a CentOS 7, I've installed *foobar* version 2, compiled from sources.

**How can I make yum aware of that install so it won't install *foobar* version 1 for dependency?**

---

#### Installation of *foobar*

```sh
$ git clone https://example.com/foobar.git
[...]
$ cd foobar
$ make && sudo make install
[...]
$ foobar --version
foobar v2
```

#### Installation of a package requiring *foobar*

```sh
$ sudo yum install baz
[...]
---> Package baz.x86_64 0:3.14.15-9 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: foobar >= 1 for package: baz-3.14.15-9.x86_64
[...]
Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================
 Package           Arch      Version      Repository   Size
==============================================================
Installing:                  
 baz               x86_64    3.14.15-9    example      1.1 M
Installing for dependencies: 
 foobar            x86_64    1.0.0-0.el7  example      4.5 M
```

I'd like yum to know *foobar* 2 is installed and since *baz* requires `foobar >= 1` or simply `foobar`, `foobar-1.0.0-0.el7.x86_64.rpm` **should not** be installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make rpm find dependencies in a specific location](https://serverfault.com/questions/829747/make-rpm-find-dependencies-in-a-specific-location)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> *"I've installed foobar version 2, compiled from sources"*

Take the extra effort when adding custom software to your system and **package your additions in a RPM**. See [Martin Streicher, 2010-01-12, *Building and distributing packages*, IBM](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-rpm1/) on how to do that.

Then install that resulting RPM  so it *can and will* play nice with your package manager's conflict and dependency handling, upgrade, downgrade and removal procedures and security reporting.

Answer (score 10):

Another option (albeit definitely not the best answer): make a dummy rpm file with the name in question.

You will need `rpmbuild` installed, and a dummy tarball.

```
mkdir ~/rpmbuild/{RPMS,SOURCES}
touch empty.txt
tar -zcf ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/example.tar.gz empty.txt
```

Write the dummy spec file. This one works for me on Fedora 29. It should be good on CentOS 7 too.

```
Name:           example
Version:        0.0.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Dummy package

Group:          Dummy
License:        CC-BY-SA 3.0
URL:            http://example.com
Source0:    example.tar.gz
BuildArch:  noarch

#BuildRequires:
#Requires:

%description
Dummy for example

%prep
:

%build
:

%install
:

%files
%doc

%changelog
```

Tweak package name and version number as necessary, and then build the package.

```
rpmbuild -ba example.spec
```

The output "binary" rpm file will be `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/example-0.0.0-1.fc29.x86_64.rpm`

Answer (score 6):

This is not how `rpm` works.

`rpm` uses a db where it stores which rpms are installed on the system. If you install some files manually, `rpm` does not know about it.

The best way to solve this is to install foobar 2 with an rpm. Other solutions would only be workaround and would not work in the long run.

Comment: You can't manually override a dependency check? Because it reads like that's what it boils down to, what OP wants.

Comment: Yes you can, but then you override all dependency checks... And you will have trouble updating afterwards

Answer (score 3):

May `rpm --nodeps` be the answer you're looking for? It was discussed in an older thread here on Serverfault.

([tell yum to ignore a single dependency](https://serverfault.com/questions/381018/tell-yum-to-ignore-a-single-dependency))

Comment: This may lead to problems down the road and basically just postpones the problem. When updating the system or installing another package later on, it can happen that some package will want to pull foobar 1 as a dependency, possibly overwriting the manually built&installed foobar 2 and causing compatibility issues.